# SQLite Select statement giving error in Android query execution

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a sql query to get the value from database when there is match in WHERE clause, but iam not able to get the values.

Please let me know if below query is properly formatted .

Query:

```
try
{

sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE,
                    null);

Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME1
    + "WHERE latitude = '"+latt1+"' AND  longitude ='"+lng1+"'" , null);

}
```

where latt1 and lng1 are string variables .

Logcat output: 03-14 12:29:33.886: ERROR/CallBlocker(8106): Could not create or Open the database

Comment: Seems likely that your problem is in the `sampleDB = ...` line. What is SAMPLE_DB_NAME?

Comment: It seems that the error is not in your select statement but in the opening of the database. Can you provide more detailed log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the "SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME1" , don't know what was wierd. I replaced SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME1 this with value and voila, got the output.

here is the updated query:

```
sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE,
                    null);

Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  profiles WHERE latitude = '"+latt1+"' AND longitude ='"+lng1+"' " , null);
```

Comment: the problem I guess was because there was no space between your name of table and Keyword "Where".